# Recuperar imagen guarda en una base de datos con mysql en java

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cordial saludo.

Necesito  que se me muestre la imagen  en el `jlabel` , la imagen ya están guardada en  la base de datos , y al darle el botón consultar necesito que la  traiga de vuelta y no lo hace , ahí esta el código que estoy intentando implementar, utilizo eclipse.

```
 try {


              java.sql.Connection conexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bdpro","root" ,"");
              java.sql.Statement comando=conexion.createStatement();
              ResultSet registro = comando.executeQuery("select nombre,precio,fecha,foto from tablapro  where id="+textField.getText());
              if (registro.next()==true) {

                  textField_1.setText(registro.getString("nombre"));
                  textField_2.setText(registro.getString("precio"));
                  Date Estado = registro.getDate("fecha");                    
                  dateChooser.setDate(Estado);


                  Blob Blob = (Blob) registro.getBlob(4);
                  byte[] imageByte = Blob.getBytes(1, (int) Blob.length()); 
                  InputStream is=new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte); 
                  BufferedImage imag=ImageIO.read(is); 
                  Image image=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(imageByte);


                  ImageIcon  icono = new ImageIcon(image);
                  lblFoto.setIcon(TamañoImg(null,icono));


               }


              conexion.close();
            } catch(SQLException | IOException ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: Seria genial que en vez de poner una imagen del codigo, lo pusieras, puedes usar las herramientas que el sitio te proporciona.

Comment: Como comentario, hasta donde me enseñaron en la universidad no es una buena práctica guardar imágens en la base de datos, algunas pocas bases de datos están especializadas para eso, como por ejemplo un tipo de datos especial para almacenar imágenes.

Comment: Igual sería bueno que agregaras el formato original de la imágen antes de guardarla, pues cambia mucho de bmp, png, jpeg y svg por dar algunos ejemplos comunes y ya asumiendo que no tienes formatos exóticos como imágenes en 3d

Comment: JFileChooser file = new JFileChooser();
    file.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter =  new FileNameExtensionFilter(".imagen","jpg","png");
    file.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
    int result = file.showSaveDialog(null);
    if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
     File  selectedFile = file.getSelectedFile();
     String path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
     lblfoto.setIcon(TamañoImg(path,null));
     imgPath = path;
     
     
    }

Comment: quisiera saber que hace `TamañoImg(null,icono)` puesto aqui puede haber un problema. por otro lado croe que esta haciendo 2 lecturas paralelas a la imagen y no se si esto pueda influir en el procesamiento.

Comment: llama el metodo tamaño, para que limagen tenga un  tamañao especifico.